# Which fiori app should i extend to customize sap smart business KPI tiles?

Tags: sapui5

We have to handle the event that is triggered when the cursor is hovered over a KPI Tile. So please can you help me to find the app i have to extend.

you find attached a screen shot of kpi generated using **kpi workspace**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWXV2.png)

Many thanks in advance,

EH

Comment: I’m not sure which Fiori app you are referring to.
Maybe a screenshot would help to identify the Fiori app you are using.

Do you see on your screen somewhere a User icon and/or an “About”-tab, where you can get some more detailed info about your app?

Comment: thank you for your reply, we are using KPI Workspace to create our KPI tiles. you find attached a screen shot of one of our kpis

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by extending sap.m.GenericTile:

```
 sap.ui.define(function () {
    "use strict";
    return sap.m.GenericTile.extend("sample.ExtendedTile", { 
            metadata: {
                events: {
                    "onmouseover" : {}  
                }
            },

//          the hover event handler, it is called when the GenericTile is hovered - no event registration required
            onmouseover : function() {}, 
});
```